# Proof of convergence for non-absolute sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I've established that the bounded sequence $A_{n}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}|x_{k}|$ converges, since it is bounded and monotonically increasing.
Now I'm trying to prove that the sequence $B_{n}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}$ (from the same $x_{k}$) is also convergent. I'm trying to use the following fact: $|B_{n}-B_{m}|=A_{n}-A_{m}$ for $n>m$. Now since $A_{n}$ is convergent I know there exists a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that when $n,m > \mathbb{N}$ and $\epsilon>0$ we have $|A_{n}-L|<\epsilon$ and $|A_{m}-L|<\epsilon$.

Can I then just say $|B_{n}-B_{m}|=A_{n}-A_{m} = A_{n}-L+L-A_{m} \leq |A_{n}-L|+|A_{m}-L| \leq 2\epsilon$?

I'm a bit confused since I'm not quite sure if it is actually true that $A_{n}$ converges to $L$ in stead of $|x_{k}|$. Because I think that if $A_{n}$ converges to $L$, then I would suppose $x_{k}$ would have to tend to $0$, but I don't see why this would be the case.

As you are probably able to see, I'm confused and any suggestions would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Cauchy criterion.

For $\varepsilon > 0$, because $(A_n)$ converges there exists $N$ such that for $p > q \geq N$, 
$$|A_p - A_q| \leq \varepsilon, \text{ i.e. } \sum_{k=q+1}^p |x_k| \leq \varepsilon$$

So for $p>q \geq N$, 
$$|B_p - B_q| = \left| \sum_{k=q+1}^p x_k \right| \leq \sum_{k=q+1}^p |x_k| \leq \varepsilon$$

This proves that $(B_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, and if your space is complete, it converges.

Comment: I see what you mean and how this would work. But does that also mean my approach is wrong?

Comment: You say that $|B_n - B_m|=A_n-A_m$, but this has no reason to be true in general...

Comment: I would argue that $|B_{n}-B_{m}|=|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} x_{k}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m} x_{k}|=|\sum\limits_{k=m+1}^{n} x_{k}|=\sum\limits_{k=m+1}^{n} |x_{k}|=A_{n}-A_{m}$. Right?

Comment: $|\sum x_k|$ is not the same thing as $\sum |x_k|$. The basic fact about $|.|$ is the triangle inequality $|\sum x_k| \leq \sum |x_k|$. If you never heard about that, it is normal you are confused with absolute convergence questions ;)

Comment: You're right, I should have written $|B_{n}-B_{m}| \leq A_{n}-A_{m}$, but then I could use the same road I did, right?

Comment: Then, you are doing the exact same thing as I did ! Except that if you want to prove that $(B_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, there is no need to introduce the limit of $(A_n)$ because you just use that $(A_n)$ is also Cauchy.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks for this insight.